# Determine what threw an exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling

I have a wpf app with various small programs one of which calculates the area of a parallelogram.  I am adding some error handling so that if the user inputs a value in the height or width boxes that is greater than `double.MaxValue`, an error message will show.  How do I determine which text box input triggered the exception so I can return it along with the error message?  The Height and Width boxes are in a User Control if that matters.

```
private void AreaOfParallelogramCalcBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramHeightTxtBox.Text) > double.MaxValue == false || (Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramWidthTxtBox.Text) > double.MaxValue == false))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Seriously?  That is a pretty big number.  Please try again.");
    }
    else
    {
        AreaOfParallelogramResultTxtBox.Text =
        CalculateAreaOfParallelogram.Calculate(Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramHeightTxtBox.Text),
        Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramWidthTxtBox.Text)).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with just checking and showing message for each TextBox separately instead of ORing both checks?

Comment: @EugenePodskal wow nothing at all I can't believe I overlooked that entirely.  Thank you.  I am quite new to all of this.

Comment: Side note, but `ToDouble(...) > double.MaxValue` will never be `true`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I noticed that, how would I address that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this probably is not the best way of doing it but this is what I ended up doing and achieved the desired results.

```
    private void AreaOfParallelogramCalcBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramHeightTxtBox.Text) > 25000000)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Height input out of range.  Height must be less than 25,000,000\n{Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramHeightTxtBox.Text):n0} is a pretty big number.  Please try again.", "*WARNING*", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
        else if (Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramWidthTxtBox.Text) > 25000000)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Width input out of range.  Width must be less than 25,000,000\n{Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramWidthTxtBox.Text):n0} is a pretty big number.  Please try again.", "*WARNING*", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            AreaOfParallelogramResultTxtBox.Text =
            CalculateAreaOfParallelogram.Calculate(Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramHeightTxtBox.Text),
            Convert.ToDouble(AreaOfParallelogramWidthTxtBox.Text)).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use source of exception

```
   try
    {
    ....
    }
    Catch(Exception ex)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Source)
    }
```